# How to avoid 'Unknown' data types when generating code with MyGeneration and Oracle 10?

Tags: c#, code-generation, mygeneration

I am attempting to generate a dOOdads business entity using MyGeneration against an Oracle database table. ( http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/dOOdads/Overview/tabid/63/Default.aspx )

The class generator appears to have issues detecting the data types.   For instance, PHOTOID is VARCHAR2.  The class generated contains the following:

```
    public virtual Unknown PHOTOID
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetUnknown(ColumnNames.PHOTOID);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetUnknown(ColumnNames.PHOTOID, value);
        }
    }
```

In other case, MyGeneration was not able to correctly id the following DATE column.

```
        public virtual Unknown SYNC_UPLOAD_DT
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetUnknown(ColumnNames.SYNC_UPLOAD_DT);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetUnknown(ColumnNames.SYNC_UPLOAD_DT, value);
        }
    }
```

If you know how to resolve this error, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Believe it or not, companies (like mine) still use this confounded software! Thanks, your suggestion lead me to figuring out a similar problem I had with `datetime2`. Turns out I had to add a line to `Languages.xml` and `DbTargets.xml` (e.g. `<Type From="datetime2" To="SqlDbType.DateTime2" />`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.   I found that I did not specify the 'Database target mapping' settings on the 'Default settings' tab.   After making this change, the generated classes were implemented with reasonable data types.